# Disabling Angular $validators

Tags: angularjs, validation

Is there any easy way to disable `$validators` and `$asyncValidators` across an entire project? The reason I'm interested in doing this is to ensure that the UI responds appropriately to the service's error responses when they happen.

I'm thinking I should be able to do this in a config block somewhere but haven't been able to find any documentation on it.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What's the purpose of it? When you say "`I'm interested in doing this is to ensure that the UI responds appropriately to the service's error responses when they happen`" ... What's "`the UI responds appropriately`" for you in this case?

Comment: The UI should respond with an error message containing a response error Id from the service. Right now, in case of service error, the UI does nothing.